# How to get a value from an input and use it as a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm not very well versed in JavaScript/jQuery, but I have managed to write a poll script that allows a user to vote on a poll and display results without refreshing the page. This is the jQuery code I've came up with:

```
 $("#poll_yes").click(function(){
                    $("#poll_options").html(ajax_load); 
                    $.post(  
                        "query.php?module=vote",  
                        {answer: "yes", pid: "<? display($_GET['username'], poll_id); ?>", to: "<?= $_GET['username'] ?>"},
                        function(responseText){  
                            $("#poll_options").html(responseText); 
                        },  
                        "html"  
                    );  
                });
$("#poll_no").click(function(){
                $("#poll_options").html(ajax_load); 
                $.post(
                    "query.php?module=vote",  
                    {answer: "no", pid: "<? display($_GET['username'], poll_id); ?>", to: "<?= $_GET['username'] ?>"},
                    function(responseText){  
                        $("#poll_options").html(responseText);  
                    },  
                    "html"  
                );  
            });
```

This would get the id of the input element on the page and based on the id it would then send a query to query.php. query.php would then send a response back and that response would then be displayed on the page.

This script is working fine but I have run into another challenge. I need multiple polls displayed on one page. I'm using php to generate the polls from a SQL database and was wondering if it was possible to pull the values for "answer: no", "answer:yes", "pid: $id", "to: $username", etc.. from an  field. If this is possible, would multiple forms be needed through out the page (for each poll)? or would one form suffice with multiple inputs?

Comment: Read the docs and it will help you a lot... There are a lot of examples on the web and it is very easy to get really well versed in JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a form for each poll, and include the pid as an input with type="hidden".  Then instead of using the click even on a yes or no button (by ID) you would attach a callback on all forms submit event.  This would also let you collapse your two functions into a single callback.

```
<script>
$("form.Poll > input[type='button']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form= $(this).closest("form");
    alert("QuestionId:"+$("input[name='QuestionId']", form).val()+" clicked on:"+$(this).val());
});
</script>
<form method='POST' action='update.php' class='Poll'>
  <input type='hidden' name='QuestionId' value='1'/>
    Do you like jQuery?
  <input type='button' name='Answer' value='Yes'/>
  <input type='button' name='Answer' value='No'/>
</form>
<form method='POST' action='update.php' class='Poll'>
  <input type='hidden' name='QuestionId' value='2'/>
    Do you like AJAX?
  <input type='button' name='Answer' value='Yes'/>
  <input type='button' name='Answer' value='No'/>
</form>
<form method='POST' action='login.php'>
  This form will fire like a normal form if you click on submit but it will not pass though the submit script defined above
  <input type='submit' name='Answer' value='Login'/>
</form>
```

This can be tested at http://jsfiddle.net/te9YL/

Comment: I'm not sure what you means by attaching a callback on all forms. Would you able to provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can get the value form the form fileds easily by using .val() function of jquery

```
$("#yourid").val();
```